# Django doesn't call model clean method

Tags: python, django

I have a view, which creates models from CSV file. I've added clean method to the model class definition, but it isn't called when model is created.

Here is example of models.py:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    tested_build = models.ForeignKey('apps.Build')
    timestamp_start = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp_end = models.DateTimeField()

class CommonMeasurement(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run)

    def clean(self):
        super(CommonMeasurement, self).clean()
        print 'here we go'
        if self.timestamp < self.run.timestamp_start or self.timestamp > self.run.timestamp_end:
            raise django_excetions.ValidationError('Measurement is outside the run')


class ClientMeasurement(CommonMeasurement):
    metric = models.ForeignKey(ClientMetric)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
```

Here is my Form View code examples:

```
class BaseMeasurementsUpload(generic_views.FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    models_to_upload = None   

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.get_full_path()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        uploader = getattr(importers, form.cleaned_data['uploader'])
        try:
            the_uploader = uploader(form.cleaned_data, self.models_to_upload)
            upload_results = the_uploader.get_result_info()
        except django_exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            custom_errors = e
        return render_to_response(self.template_name,
                                  {'upload_results': upload_results,
                                   'custom_errors': custom_errors},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))


class ClientMeasurementsUploadView(BaseMeasurementsUpload):
    form_class = forms.ClientMeasurementsUploadForm
    models_to_upload = models.ClientMeasurement

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        uploaders = (('MeasurementsSimpleCsv', importers.MeasurementsSimpleCsv.__doc__),
                     ('ClientMeasurementsBulkCsv', importers.ClientMeasurementsBulkCsv.__doc__,))
        if self.request.POST:
            # get bound form
            return self.form_class(uploaders,
                                   self.request.POST,
                                   self.request.FILES)
        else:
            return forms.ClientMeasurementsUploadForm(uploaders)
```

importers perform actual validation and call create method for each model.

Comment: Can you post your view code? Perhaps you are not calling is_valid on your ModelForm?

Comment: `clean` is for `ModelForm` or `Form` objects. Not for models. this would _never_ get called automatically.

Comment: @karthikr -- while you're correct that this `clean()` will not be called automatically, you're incorrect that it's "not for models" -- see the [documentation on this point](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found a solution to override method:

```
class CommonMeasurement(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run)

    objects = models.Manager()
    analyzes = managers.MeasureStatManager()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        return super(CommonMeasurement, self).save(**kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super(CommonMeasurement, self).clean()
        print 'here we go'
        if self.timestamp < self.run.timestamp_start or self.timestamp > self.run.timestamp_end:
            raise django_excetions.ValidationError('Measurement is outside the run')
```

But I'm not sure that it can be a good decision.

Comment: I believe calling clean from save will prevent your ValidationError from reaching your view/template, so the user would not see the error message but a debug message w/traceback if debug=True or a server error if debug is False.

Comment: Actually, validation error is successfully passed to upper view layer.

Comment: This works however Django doesn't like ValidationError during save() and return a (horrible) 500 Server Error instead of 400 Bad Request.  I'm still looking for solution on this.

Comment: I'm using Django==2.2.5 and djangorestframework==3.10.3 and this annoying 500 error is still happening! Any solutions?

Comment: if there are people with problem of  500 debug message instead of  with normal admin error message - in django==3.2 its better call `ValidationError` from `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError`

Comment: The code flow shouldn't be able to reach `save()` if the object is not valid, hence, if you get `save()` called, it means Django shouldn't expect `ValidationError` on that level and if it happens, then it's something related to functionality, not validation.

Answer (score 53):

To call the model clean method we will override save method. Check the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

```
class CommonMeasurement(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run)

    def clean(self):
        if self.timestamp < self.run.timestamp_start or self.timestamp > self.run.timestamp_end:
            raise django_excetions.ValidationError('Measurement is outside the run')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(CommonMeasurement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. In `djangorestframework`, the clean method not calling which using this method my problem solved.

Comment: @SirSaleh did you manage to get an error sent back to the REST api or did it just showed a debugger error?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently model.clean() is never called to ensure backward compatibility. For more information on this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13100

Comment: Is it bad practice to use my solution? Which compatibility I break with auto-calling clean() method from save?

Comment: 1. My solution was to move all the code I would have put in clean() in save(). In that respect I think your solution is cleaner. 2. I have no idea what it is supposed to break.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in newer versions of Django the `ModelForm.full_clean` does call it's instance's `full_clean` method:

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/14e2b1/django/forms/models.py#L403

Comment: Yes, but `save` doesn't call `full_clean` either.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/14e2b1b065085c1d2d3e94ebaeefe25e12595a00/django/forms/models.py#L403 for a link that won't become confusingly invalid in future.

Comment: Thanks @AdamBarnes, I've updated the link in the answer ;)