# Clean method in django model not triggered

Tags: django

In my model my clean method limits to have only one active record.

So in clean method I limit only one combination for each lease where it is `active = True` and `is_terminated = False`

```
 class LeaseTerm(CommonInfo):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        start_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='start_period' )
        end_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='end_period')
        lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
        increase  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)


        def clean(self):
                model = self.__class__
                if self.lease_id and (self.is_terminated == False) and model.objects.filter(lease=self.lease, is_active=True ).exclude(id=self.id).count() > 0:
                    raise ValidationError('!Lease has a active Term , terminate existing term  prior to creation of a new one'.format(self.lease))
```

And this is view to create  a new term

```
def term_new(request,pk,uri):
    lease = get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=pk)
    title = 'term'
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaseTermForm(request.POST)
        form.lease = lease
        if form.is_valid():
            term = form.save(commit=False)  
            #term.lease = lease      
            term.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(term.id) + "-SUCCESS Object created sucssefully")


            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = LeaseTermForm()
    return render(request, 'object_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title': title, 'extend': EXTEND})
```

form

```
class LeaseTermForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LeaseTerm
        fields = [  'amount',
        'start_period','end_period', 'increase','is_terminated' ]
```

However the clean method is not triggered any more, it doesn't prevent users from creating new records under same lease with `is_active = True` and `is_terminated = False`

What could be the reason?

Comment: I guess you need to call it when you override save method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803112/django-doesnt-call-model-clean-method call `full_clean` there.

Comment: Yes, good idea thank you,  it does trigger it. But now I am getting 500 error page from Raising the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `form.is_valid()` method doesn't call the models `clean` method, but cleans the form fields and then tries to save it. The error is raised during saving and because you don't handle it yourself, it is raised. One (pretty bad) way of fixing it would be this:

```
def term_new(request,pk,uri):
    lease = get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=pk)
    title = 'term'
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaseTermForm(request.POST)
        form.lease = lease
        if form.is_valid():
            term = form.save(commit=False)  
            #term.lease = lease  
            try:    
                term.save()
            except ValidationError:
                pass # Handle returning errors
```

A better way to do it would be to move the cleaning to one of form's cleaning methods.