# Django: How to set a integer field max value based on Foreign Key atribute?

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model:

```
class Atividades_cumpridas(models.Model):
    id_atividade = models.ForeignKey(Atividade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_jogador = models.ForeignKey(Jogador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pontos_xp_ganhos = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        str = self.id_atividade.nome_atividade + ' - ' + self.id_jogador.nome_jogador
        return str
```

and i want to set the `pntos_xp_ganhos` max value based on `Atividade.pontos_XP_maximo`. How can I do that and show the max value on the admin editing page?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do it,

1. Using custom validators
2. Using builtin validators

**custom validators:**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_range(value):
    if value > Atividade.pontos_XP_maximo:
        raise ValidationError('Max value should be %s' % Atividade.pontos_XP_maximo
        )

class Atividades_cumpridas(models.Model):
        ...
        ...
        pontos_xp_ganhos = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_range])
```

**Using builtin validators:**

```
MIN = 0
MAX = Atividade.pontos_XP_maximo
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Atividades_cumpridas(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    pontos_xp_ganhos = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(MIN), MaxValueValidator(MAX)]
```

Comment: but for each Atividade i have a different pontos_XP_maximo

Comment: @RonaldoSilveira can please explain with example ?

Comment: For example: If i have an Atividade with id = 1, i would have, let's say, pontos_XP_maximo = 30. For the Atividade with id = 2, it would be 50.

Comment: @RonaldoSilveira is Atividade and pontos_XP_maximo are predefined >

Comment: No, Atividade is a model and pontos_XP_maximo is a field. So they are in te database and may be altered.

Comment: @RonaldoSilveira can u please edit your question with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can override `clean()` method in your model and do the validation there. As [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) states:

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do validation that requires access to more than a single field.

And in your case, you want to do a validation that requires access to more than a single field, which makes `clean` a proper method to do what you desire.

Note, however, that like `Model.full_clean()`, a model’s `clean()` method is not invoked when you call your model’s `save()` method.
You can see how to fix this here: [Django doesn't call model clean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803112/django-doesnt-call-model-clean-method)