# Validate a model instance for unique drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a "Recipes" model and I want to prevent the creation of duplicate models with the same fields. Specifically, I want to throw a validation error if a model instance already exists with the same field values.

This is my current code:

```py
def validate_recipe(self, value):
   recipes = Recipe.objects.all().filter(author=self.context['request'].user)
   for rec in recipes:
       if rec._meta.fields == value._meta.fields:
           raise serializers.ValidationError(
           {'errors': 'Do you have this recipe!'}
           )
   return value
```

Here are the images of the output I am currently getting:

[image]

[image]

UPD:
I use unique_together, but it doesn't work

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipe/', null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredients,
        through='RecipeIngredients'
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Teg
    )
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(help_text='Cooking time')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('author', 'name', 'image',
                                            'text', 'cooking_time')
```

Comment: You should add unique constraints on your receipt model. You can use unique_together with the user field if you like to have same receipts but not for the same user.

Comment: But I have ManyToMany relationships in my model and it also needs to be checked

Comment: Show your model definition with all the unique_together and such.

Comment: Well, placing a UQ on ImageField and long text field is not something usual. I'd say that author+name should be good enough. Remove this `_meta.fields` try and make sure you did `makemigrations + migrate` after adding unique_together. Also consider using model's `clean` method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803112/django-doesnt-call-model-clean-method

Comment: @Ivan Starostin
Thanks! How can I mark your answer?

Comment: it's fine, thanks. glad if it helped